# Can I concat an endpoint address to a variable in app.config file?

Tags: c#

Is this possible in appconfig file?

```
<add key="@IPAddress" value="http://00.00.00.00:0000"/>
```

replace this:

```
<endpoint address="http://00.00.00.00:0000/some/something"
               binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding"
```

with this:

```
<endpoint address="@IPaddress/some/something"
               binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding"
```

Comment: I don't believe so.  Why do you want to do this (i.e., what are you attempting to accomplish)?

Comment: There are too many end point address and I do not want to find and replace the ip address each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in config. But you can change your address in runtime, like this

```
var confAddress=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IPAddress"];
string address = confAddress+"/some/something";
using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(yourContract), address))
{
   //Consume your service
}
```